# PostDoc while Serving in the Military

Tags: phd, postdocs

I am currently full-time military, and I am due to graduate in a year with a Ph.D. in Systems Engineering, are there opportunities to do post doc work "part time"?

Comment: Was the PhD done at a military institution (Naval Postgraduate School, Air Force Institute of Technology, etc. in the USA)? Was it done on assignment from the military (happens quite a bit)? What assignment does the military have in mind for you once you have your degree?

Comment: Its at Colorado state done in my spare time, the military gets nothing out of it unless I'm selected for Professor at the academy.

Comment: Congrats and good luck with an academy position. I just closed on a house in Fort Collins…

Answer (score 6):

Without knowing specifics (such as your country, branch of service, etc.), consider reaching out agency's research program.

For example, the US Military has the [Office of the Under Secretary of Defense for Research and Engineering](https://www.cto.mil/) that does and publishers research. Perhaps you could include/leverage some of your official military duties to create a post-doc like experience.

Answer (score 4):

That would be unusual, but you might be able to arrange something, especially if you don't require much compensation for it. Normally, though, a post doc is pretty intense.

But you might be able to arrange some sort of a collaborative arrangement with a professor without an employment contract, but just two people interested in a common project. It would be easiest if you were co-located, but not impossible otherwise.

So, perhaps not a formal postdoc, but something like postdoc work as you suggest. And it might give you some publications and appropriate letters of recommendation for furthering your career if you leave the military.